# Why is there no type conversion exception in this code?

Tags: java

This is from *Thinking in Java*

```
class Snow {}
class Powder extends Snow {}
class Light extends Powder {}
class Heavy extends Powder {}
class Crusty extends Snow {}
class Slush extends Snow {}

public class AsListInference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //The book says it won't compile, but actually it does.
        List<Snow> snow2 = Arrays.asList(new Light(), new Heavy());
    }
}
```

Here is my Java enviroment:

1. java version "1.8.0_60"
2. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
3. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: Because there should not be one. `Light` and `Heavy` are subclasses of Snow, and can therefore be added to a `List` of `Snow`.

Comment: In Java 7 this code gives me a compilation error - `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Powder> to List<Snow>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the book is right. The difference here is the Java version.

[*Thinking in Java*](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4) targets Java 5/6 (as per the cover). For this version of Java (and with Java 7 also), the snippet won't compile with `javac`. The error is:

> incompatible types: `java.util.List<Powder>` cannot be converted to `java.util.List<Snow>`

With Java 8, this compiles just fine: the type-inference system was improved.

Answer (score 2):

The book is apparently expecting the compiler to determine the type of the right-hand side as `List<Powder>`, which is not a `List<Snow>`. However, since `Arrays.<T>asList(T ...)` has its own self-contained scope for `T`, the compiler is able to infer that the correct bound should be `Snow` and that both `Light` and `Heavy` are `Snow`.

I don't have a Java 7 compiler on hand, but Java 8 did bring some improvements in [generic type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) that may be what lets the compiler solve this particular type bound.